# Does GWT Graphics support mobile devices?

Tags: gwt, svg, vector-graphics, vml

I'm looking for a cross-browser vector graphics library for GWT and I came across [GWT Graphics](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-graphics/).

The library has been tested to work with the following browsers:

- Internet Explorer 6 and newer (6,7 and 8 use VML rendering, 9 uses SVG)
- Firefox 3.0 and newer
- Safari 3.2 and newer
- Opera 9.6 and newer
- Google Chrome

Does it work on any mobile device as well?

Do you know any alternative for drawing vector graphics in GWT?

Comment: It might, it depends on the SVG emitted, and whether it makes good choices about the type of device if there are variances. Although SVG support on mobile devices isn't as strong as on desktop browsers (http://caniuse.com/#cats=SVG). The most well tested SVG options are likely not GWT based.

Comment: (it also looks like an abandoned project from looking at commits and browsing the issues list).

Comment: GXT 3's draw package in the charting jar fits those requirements - uses either SVG or VML depending on the browser. The charts are are implemented using these features, but you can rely on the Sprite types to work on a DrawComponent without involving a Chart.

Comment: If you want to use chart consider using [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com//) + [highcharts gwt](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT mobile cross-platform drawing performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269456/gwt-mobile-cross-platform-drawing-performance)